# how to fix Access denied for user ''@'***' (using password: NO) issue

Tags: mysql, asp.net, web

```
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();

        Conn = new MySqlConnection();
        //    Conn.Open();


       MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("sp_rpt_Show_User_Details", Conn);

        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        ReportDocument myrpt = new ReportDocument();
        da.Fill(ds.agenthistorycumulative);


        myrpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport2.rpt"));
        CrystalReport2 c = new CrystalReport2();
        c.SetDataSource(ds);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = c;
```

if i comment the da.fill method..that time show the report but didnt show data..only table fields name...if i uncomment the da.fill() method then give the Authentication to host '' for user '' ...msg...
im not 100% sure my code is correct...but i instead of stored procedures i pass the query..it is working well...

```
       help me
```

Comment: please mention heading well! refer : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry for inconvenience.